# Invalid SOS parameters for sequential JPEG in R OpenCV

Tags: r, opencv

I tried in R to open a jpg image using the opencv library, using this code:

```
library(opencv)
sample  <- ocv_read("Sample.jpg")
```

But I get this message:

`Invalid SOS parameters for sequential JPEG`

I'm not sure why I receive this message. I tried the following code to open the file:

```
sample  <- ocv_read(path = "Sample.jpg")
```

I would like to understand that SOS parameter, please could you help me with this issue?

Regards,

Alexis

p.d. Attached is part of the photo, because it contains the ID number and its better not to expose it.

[image: Cropped image]

Comment: Have you tried loading a different JPEG file. This sounds like your image jpeg sequencing is defective.

Comment: Hello Guilherme Vogt, yes, I tried loading a different jpeg file and it worked, and I took a screenshoot of the original picture and worked fine too. Is that jpg files from a mobile phone could be badly sequenced? Please, could you suggest an alternative to bypass that issue? Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide the original image? It seems to be a recurrent issue on jpegs from [Samsung phones.](https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/1578) I can think of a workaround, not in R though...

Comment: Hello @GuilhermeVogt, as requested I attached the picture but cropped because the person has his ID card beside him, Thank you in advance for your help.